# VS 2013 Schema Compare not updating target

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have a database project on VS 2013 migrated from 2010  and when I do a schema compare with source Database and target the DB project, its not updating the project after I pressed the update button. I have tried it a number of times but its not working. Do you you have any clue?

Comment: Make sure all schema are selected

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same issue and Fisseha's comment on another answer really helped me.

> Sorry not working on that project anymore. But I remember that somehow
>   it got to do with setting -> application scope-> checking/unchecking
>   permission. I have no idea why. – Fisseha Apr 23 '15 at 15:57

By unchecking the permission box under the settings -> application scope, it was able to run the update on the data project itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem as well. I just experienced it on my own machine.

This was when my source SQL Server instance was referenced using a server [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx), ours is something like WorkplaceDev, which points to the local instance on my machine. When I set up the schema compare using WorkplaceDev\DatabaseName the schema compare showed the changes but didn't update the destination.

I then tried again referencing the database on my machine directly (JimsMachine\DatabaseName) and it worked without issue.

Sorry I'm a bit late to the party, but can you see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Sorry not working on that project anymore. But I remember that somehow it got to do with setting -> application scope-> checking/unchecking permission. I have no idea why.